# Lua: Inverse of string.char()?

Tags: sorting, lua, char

I'm wondering if there is a function that does the exact opposite of string.char(). It would be convenient to get a number value from letters in order to sort things alphabetically.

Comment: See `string.byte`

Comment: You don't need to turn chars into numbers to sort things alphabetically. What problem are you really trying to solve?

Answer (score 4):

```
string.byte()
```

Is probably what you're looking for.

Answer (score 4):

To get the first UTF-8 Byte of a string, you can use either `string.byte` or `str:byte()` where str is your string in question.

However, if you're sorting a table, or doing a sort in general, Lua actually has you covered! You can compare two strings as if they were numbers! `"A" < "B"` returns `true` and `"B" < "A"` returns `false`. This also works for multiple letters in a string. `"Ba" > "Aa"` and `"Ab" > "Aa"` and so on. So you can do `table.sort(t)` or if you're sorting by a sub value, `table.sort(t,function(a,b) return a.text < b.text end)`. Hope this helps!